# Storing Objects in Dictionary Values

Tags: python, object, dictionary, memory, storage

```
class Draw():
  '''Class using, for example opengl, to display something on the screen'''
  def add(self,size,file_name):
    file_name= file_name
    size = size
class Image(Draw):
  def __init__(self,size,file_name):
    self.size = size
    self.add(self.size,file_name)

class Gui():
  file_names = ['a.jpg','b.jpg']
  images = {}
  def __init__(self):
    for e in self.file_names:
      self.image = Image((50,50),file_name=e)
      self.images[e] = self.image
  def print_size(self):
    print(self.image.size)
a = Gui()
a.print_size() #this gives me a proper (50,50) size
for e in a.images.values():
  print(e.size) #this gives me wrong size
```

This is simplified version of my code. I don't have experience with storing objects in dictionary values.
My question is: is this normal that I don't access the right attributes of stored objects in dictionary? In this sample everything works ok, but is this a wrong way to writing code?

Comment: It's not the problem, but your `add` method does absolutely nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

I run your code and it works as it should. In terminal there was printed

> (50, 50)
>
> (50, 50)
>
> (50, 50)

Did you expected something else? Now I will try to explain few things.

```
class Draw():
  '''Class using, for example opengl, to display something on the screen'''
```

I may not fully understand how it is supposed to work, but if you want to save size and file_name in add method you shouls use self. before variables, so it would look like

```
  def add(self,size,file_name):
    self.file_name = file_name
    self.size = size

class Image(Draw):
  def __init__(self,size,file_name):
    self.size = size
    self.add(self.size,file_name)

class Gui():
    file_names = ['a.jpg','b.jpg']
    images = {}
  def __init__(self):
```

Now in every iteration you create new Image with the same size (50, 50), but diffrent filename and assing to map.

```
    for e in self.file_names:
      self.image = Image((50,50),file_name=e)
      self.images[e] = self.image
```

In loop in above init method to self.image you assing the last image you created based on file_names ('b.jpg'), so self.image and self.images['b.jpg'] points to the same object.

Method print_size prints size of self.image / self.images['b.jpg'], which is (50, 50)

```
  def print_size(self):
    print(self.image.size)

a = Gui()
a.print_size() #this gives me a proper (50,50) size
```

Now you iterate on your images. There are 2: the one with file_name 'a.jpg' and second that was already printed before 'b.jpg'. Both of them has the same size of (50, 50).

```
for e in a.images.values():
  print(e.size) #this gives me wrong size
```

I hope I clarified a little bit and it will help you

Comment: Thank you for you contribution. The class Draw() is abstract, right i should use self instance in that. I replace Kivy class Widget() and its parents with my class Draw(): just to code appear simpler. I was wondering if I did everything correctly elsewere in the code I published here.

Comment: You didn't said what output had you expected. Besides, you can create instance of class Draw, so it is not abstact. If you want to create abstract class in python, check out [abc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) module